# gtk.FileChooser backend example

Tags: gtk

According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkfilechooserdialog.html)`gtk.FileChooserDialog(title=None, parent=None, action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, buttons=None, backend=None)` accepts a backend parameter: `backend :
The name of the specific filesystem backend to use.`

Can someone explain how this can be used, as after trawling for quite some time the `None` default seems to be the only use case I can find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a concrete example, but according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/unstable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) the parameter was used to specify a custom VFS type, such as `gnome-vfs` to use GVFS. It was deprecated in 2.14, which was released in 2008, and is completely absent in GTK+ 3. (GVFS can now use fuse to mount its VFS directly onto the filesystem.) You don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, although I was rather hoping it meant something else ;)

Comment: What would that something else be?

Comment: The application I'm building supports data export, but I do not want the user to be able to save exported data to the local filesystem, but only to a USB Flash Drive. Naively, I was hoping that FileChooser would allow such a thing to be specified, hence the question about the backend parameter, but your answer and link along with further rummaging around suggests that this is not possible.